# admin search for generic foreign key django

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

I am trying to put admin search on model in generic foreign key is present.

admin.py

```
class privacySettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (
                'field_name',
                'level',

            )
        }),
        (('page/article'), {
            'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-open',),
            'fields': ('content_type', 'object_id', )
        }),
    )
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
        'generic': [['content_type', 'object_id']],
    }
    search_fields = ('object_id',)
```

i am able to search using `object_id`. But i want search using the feilds of that `object_id` object.

ex. User has a foreign key to model. then i want to search privacy setting of that user using `username`, `first_name`, `email` and `last_name`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your models....

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes:

In models.py:

```
class PrivacySettings(models.Model):
    ...
    def object_username(self):
        return self.object.username
    object_username = property(object_username)

    def object_first_name(self):
        return self.object.first_name
    object_first_name = property(object_first_name)

    def object_last_name(self):
        return self.object.last_name
    object_last_name = property(object_last_name)

    def object_email(self):
        return self.object.email
    object_email = property(object_email)
```

In admin.py:

```
class PrivacySettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = PrivacySettings
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (
                'field_name',
                'level',

            )
        }),
        (('page/article'), {
            'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-open',),
            'fields': ('content_type', 'object_id', )
        }),
    )
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
        'generic': [['content_type', 'object_id']],
    }
    search_fields = ('object_id', 'object_username', 'object_first_name',
                     'object_last_name', 'object_email')
```

Comment: I unknown what @property not worked for you but i applied some changes in code specially i changed properties definitioning and implementing method...

Comment: Using 'p= property(function)' also did not work. Doesn't allow me to use it in the search_fields. Django 1.7 here.